# How to display username in multiple pages using flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have encountered a problem of having the username not being shown on all the pages running under my flask application, it only runs at the home page because I return it from the login function. However, I don't know how could I get all the pages being called to have the username visible in all of them.

In the code attached, the `def featured_books()` doesn't return the username as it should be, instead it returns it as 1. How to solve this issue?

flask.py

```
 @app.route('/')
 # Gets correct username
 @app.route('/index')
 def home(post=1):
    return render_template("index.html", username=post)  

 # Doesn't get the username 
 @app.route('/featured_books')
 def featured_books(post=1):
    return render_template("featured_books.html", username=post)

 @app.route('/login')
 def login(post=1):
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        return home(post)

 @app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
 def do_login():
    POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
    POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])
    secure_password = sha512_crypt.encrypt(POST_PASSWORD)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    s = Session()
    query = s.query(User_reg).filter(User_reg.username.in_([POST_USERNAME]), 
            User_reg.password.in_([POST_PASSWORD]))
    result = query.first()
    if result:
        session['logged_in'] = True
    else:
        flash('Wrong password!')
    return login(POST_USERNAME)
```

Comment: Example with session being used to hold the information about user: https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-session-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on the same thing and came across your question.
Have you figured it out?

Some suggest using Flask-Login extension to handle session management. Because I'm working on a simple app I decided to put the user name into a session cookie. Then can just grab it from the session on another page. Seemed like the path of least resistance, though, may not be the best choice.

Storing it in route.py

```
session['user_name'] = user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname
```

Grabbing it from an html page

```
<h3> Welcome, {{session['user_name']}}! </h3>
```